# Bootstrap image does not dynamically resize in row

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that overflows my row. I read online that clearfix prevents this from happening. But having applied this, my image appears as a very thin line with hardly anything visible. My code is visible below. How do I ensure that my image dynamically resizes itself within this container?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <img src="url" alt="A picture" id="heading-img" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">other things</div>              
</div>
```

Comment: How about the class `img-responsive`?

Comment: tried that too, sorry should have included that in code will edit now

Comment: I've never had a problem with it so can you make a fiddle which reproduces this behavior when using `img-responsive`?

Comment: It's odd. I cannot replicate the same error on fiddle Is the problem my browser? https://jsfiddle.net/sqxLecqp/.

Comment: If you are viewing the page and the fiddle in the same browser then I don't think it is the browser...

Comment: did not correctly update external dependencies on my fiddle, and couldnt seem to update my comment, so here it is again: jsfiddle.net/sqxLecqp/1/

Comment: It is quite responsive on my end. I'm not seeing what the problem is. If I resize the window the image resizes accordingly.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what's happening http://tinypic.com/r/24lv2m9/8

Answer (score 0):

add class="img-responsive" if you're using bootstrap css.

Comment: img-responsive did not seem to help either

Comment: can you share your code via jsfiddle/codepen or other editors online?